# Display a Message box based on a value in a cell in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to display a browser message box based on a particular value in range. I tried with the following

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var panType = sheet.getRange("A4:A100").getValues();
  if (panType=="CSF");
  Browser.msgBox('Make sure you enter the PAN No in the alloted slot');
}
```

But the problem is, with each and every edit in any cell, the message box pops up.

The said range `A4:A100` has a validation dropdown with options like "**New**" and "**CSF**". So whenever the value **CSF** is chosen, the dialogue box should popup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if it is the xorrect sheet, column, and value. Event has these values. If they match, show your messagebox.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
  if(sheet=="Sheet1"){
     if(editedCell.getColumn() == 1 && event.value=="CSF"){   
        Browser.msgBox('Make sure you enter the PAN No in the alloted slot');
  }}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined.

Comment: Here is mt test spreadsheet. Make a copy and try it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOMYN0Dej3UbZe-6FRQ8zXYcx6XAfktnkQAXou-bCAc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate this. However, can you make it editable for me? I am unable to add either CSF or New and see any changes. I am really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: If you make a copy, you can edit. I changed it so you can edit without making a copy.

Comment: Ed Nelson. Thanks for this. The funny thing is that when I copy it on my gmail spreadsheet it works fine but when I do the same on my G Suite spreadsheet I get the "undefined source" error. Any idea why so?

Comment: I don't use G Suite so I really don't know. My guess would be a problem with Browser.msgBox. ui.prompt might work. I changed the sample spreadsheet. Give that a try.